# Arrange rectangle in the background

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a question.
When I create a rectangle in Python Tkinter I want, that this rectangle is created in the background. So that other rectangles are in the foreground.

Example:

```
rectangle_1 = canvas.create_rectangle(10, 15, 20, 25, fill=black, outline='#b51e00', width=3, dash=(25, 1))
rectangle_2 = canvas.create_rectangle(100, 105, 120, 125, fill=yellow, outline='#b51e00', width=3, dash=(25, 1))
rectangle_3_lowest = canvas.create_rectangle(10, 15, 200, 250, fill=red, outline='#b51e00', width=3, dash=(25, 1))
```

So now, I'm asking myself, how to arrange the rectangle_3_lowest behind the other two despite it was created at last!

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `canvas.lower(rectangle_3_lowest)` like this:

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
canvas.pack()

rectangle_1 = canvas.create_rectangle(10, 15, 20, 25, fill="black")
rectangle_2 = canvas.create_rectangle(100, 105, 120, 125, fill="yellow")
rectangle_3_lowest = canvas.create_rectangle(10, 15, 200, 250, fill="red")

canvas.lower(rectangle_3_lowest)

root.mainloop()
```